# Let the user add new picklist value in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have an entity field with a picklist and I want to let the user add new values to this when it's necessary. For now, I just can add new values from the Solution > Entity > Fields panel. Can this be done also when creating a new instance of the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by calling the MetadataService.  Capture the text value for the new entry from the user then add this via a call to the MetadataService in a plugin.

If it's likely that users will be adding a sufficient number of values themselves I'd consider using a lookup rather than a picklist.

Comment: +1 also If the values of a configuration are scalables they should be lookups, not OptionSet values, consider this alessandro with your architect.